# Oracle spatial: Point cluster vs MultiPoint?

Tags: oracle-spatial

I'm reading Oracle's documentation and i can't see the difference between `Point cluster` and `MultiPoint` element type.

The following example code is from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm)

```
INSERT INTO t1 (i, d, g)
VALUES (
  16,
  'Point cluster',
  sdo_geometry (2005, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array (1,1,3), 
    sdo_ordinate_array (50,5, 55,7, 60,5))
);
INSERT INTO t1 (i, d, g)
VALUES (
  17,
  'Multipoint',
  sdo_geometry (2005, null, null, sdo_elem_info_array (1,1,1, 3,1,1, 5,1,1), 
    sdo_ordinate_array (65,5, 70,7, 75,5))
);
```

It seems that:

`Point cluster` is **one** element (of many points -in that example 3 points: 50,5, 55,7, 60,5) as it needs **one** triplet in `sdo_elem_info_array`

`MultiPoint` is **many** elements ( and each element is a `Point` -in that example 3 points: 65,5, 70,7, 75,5) as it needs **three** triplets in `sdo_elem_info_array`

And further down documentation refers to them as the same thing(?):

```
2.5.8 Several Geometry Types
Example 2-13 creates a table and inserts various geometries,
including multipoints (point clusters), multipolygons, and collections...
```

What is this mess? What's the difference? The `sdo_geometry` **requires** different `sdo_elem_info_array` parameters so there must be a difference between those types?

Answer (score 4):

You are creating the same `MultiPoint` geometry with different constructor parameters for `SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY`. You are defining the `GTYPE` of your geometry with the first parameter of the constructor (2005) where the 5 says that your geometry is a MultiPoint!

You can also check the GTYPE of your geometry like this:

```
SELECT x.g.GET_GTYPE() AS geometry_type FROM t1 x WHERE x.i = 16;
-- returns 5
SELECT x.g.GET_GTYPE() AS geometry_type FROM t1 x WHERE x.i = 17;
-- returns 5
```

The difference is just in the creation of the `SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY` which takes attributes of the type `SDO_ELEM_INFO`. Each `SDO_ELEM_INFO` is a triple of numbers where the digits mean:

1. `SDO_STARTING_OFFSET`: The index in `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY` where this (sub-)geometry begins.
2. `SDO_ETYPE`: The geometry (element) type of the (sub-)geometry (where 1 means point!)
3. `SDO_INTERPRETATION`: The specification of the element type (which relies on the `SDO_ETYPE`). For points

   - 1 means a single point -> `SFA: Point`
   - n > 1 means a collection of n points -> `SFA:MultiPoint`

Your first point (id 16) is created using a value of 3 for `SDO_INTERPRETATION` which means that your ordinates are interpreted as a collection of points.

The second point (id 17) is created using a value of 1 for  `SDO_INTERPRETATION` which means that your ordinates are interpreted as single points. This is why the `SDO_STARTING_OFFSET` has to specify the start index for each of your points (1, 3, 5).